# typo3temp directory with 02775 premission blocks css-files

Tags: css, linux, permissions, typo3, acl

On my `typo3temp/` directory the permissions are `02775`. It seems that the permissions block the browser to load css-files. What does 02 in 02775 means and how can i change it into 775?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"What does 02 in 02775 means and how can i change it into 775?"* - For some reason, this does not feel like a programming or development question.

Comment: this is a permission question on linux

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the permissions are your problems. Probably the owner and group of folder and files might be the problem.
In general we assume that you access files via ssh and your user is not the same than the apache user. But both have the same primary group, so the group access is important.
But sometimes this assumption is wrong and your ssh-user and the apache user are not in the same group and then the rights 0775 (or 02775) is not enough. then you need 0777 (or 02777).
Or change the group of the folder/files: `chgrp`.

For further files and folders you might change your primary group to that of the apache user: see the `usermod` command.

Answer (score -1):

The "2" from "2775" on a directory means: If a file / directory is created inside this directory that has "2" set, the group of that new file / dir is set to the same value as the directory, overriding the primary group of the creating user.

Comment: is this the reason, that the browser can't load the css-file from temp-file with 02775 permission?

Comment: Probably no, depends on your web server user and his access rights. If you're doing administration on this level, you may need to have a closer look on how unix handles users, groups and their file/dir access rights.